# BW image showing grays

Tags: python, image

I am trying to convert a color image to pure BW. I looked around for some code to do this and settled with

```
im = Image.open("mat.jpg")
gray = im.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
bw.save("result_bw.jpg")
```

However, the result still has grays!

So, I tried to do it myself:

```
floskel = Image.open("result_bw.jpg")
flopix = floskel.load()

for i in range (0,floskel.size[0]):
    for j in range (0, floskel.size[1]):
        print flopix[i,j]
        if flopix[i,j]>100:
            flopix[i,j]=255
        else:
            flopix[i,j]=0
```

But, STILL, there are grays in the image.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: do you use PIL or PILLOW ?

Comment: PIL (writing this to satisfy char count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sebdelsol mentioned, it's much better to use `im.convert('1')` directly on the colour source image. The standard PIL "dither" is Floyd-Steinberg error diffusion, which is generally pretty good (depending on the image), but there are a variety of other options, eg random dither and ordered dither, although you'd have to code them yourself, so they'd be quite a bit slower.

The conversion algorithm(s) you use in the code in the OP is just simple thresholding, which generally loses a **lot** of detail, although it's easy to write. But I guess in this case you were just trying to confirm your theory about grey pixels being present in the final image. But as sebdelsol said, it just *looks* like there are grey pixels due to the "noise", i.e. regions containing a lot of black and white pixels mixed together, which you should be able to verify if you zoom into the image.

FWIW, if you do want to do your own pixel-by-pixel processing of whole images it's more efficient to get a list of pixels using `im.getdata()` and put them back into an image with `im.putdata()`, rather than doing that `flopix[i,j]` stuff. Of course, if you don't need to know coordinates, algorithms that use `im.point()` are usually pretty quick.

Finally, JPEG isn't really suitable for B&W images, it was designed for images with (mostly) continuous tone. Try saving as PNG; the resulting files will probably be a **lot** smaller than the equivalent JPEGs. It's possible to reduce JPEG file size by saving with low quality settings, but the results generally don't look very good.

Comment: Thanks for all of the info! When I save PNG the greys disappear. It wasn't mixed pixels because I was looking at a 10X10 pixel image--the JPEG definitely showed some of the pixels as grey.

Comment: My pleasure! `the JPEG definitely showed some of the pixels as grey` Hmmm. Ok, in that case those grey pixels are an artifact of the way JPEG quantizes and compresses image data. Its algorithms (which use the Discrete Cosine Transform) work best with gradual contrast changes and don't cope so well with high contrast transitions. This [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression) article kind of explains it, but I admit it is pretty technical.

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather use `convert` to produce a mode('1') image. It would be faster and better since it use dithering by default.

```
bw = im.convert('1')
```

The greys you see appear probably in the parts of the image with noise near the 128 level, that produces high frequency B&W that looks grey.